# Convergence of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis

In order to prove convergence of some sequence of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ w.r.t $||\cdot||$ norm one have to show that $\lim_{m\to \infty}\left( \sum_{i=1}^n (a_{mi} - l_1)^2 )\right)^{1/2}$? For instance, $ a_{m} = (1/m, 1/m^2)$, then 
$$
\lim_{m\to \infty} ||a_m|| = \lim_{m\to\infty} \left( \frac{1}{m^2} + \frac{1}{m^4}  \right)^{1/2} = 0
$$
is it legitimate/enough to deduce that $\{a_{m} \}_{m\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $(0,0)$? 
Are there any other approaches to such problems?

Comment: When $v_j=(a_{1,j},...,a_{n,j})\in R^2,$ the series $(v_j)_{j\in N}$ converges in norm to $(b_,...,b_n)$  iff $\lim_{j\to \infty}a_{k,j}=b_k$ for each $k=1,...,n.$

Comment: So it better to deal with such vectors by dealing separately with each entry?

Comment: Often it is easier.It depends on the context.